# JAVASCRIPT DOM searching or DOM relation, which is the faster way?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

Suppose I have following HTML structure

```
<div>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need that when I click "foo", the innerHTML of "bar" turned into "hello". I have basically two ways to get to the "bar" element:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick=function(){
    document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML="hello";
}

document.getElementById("foo").onclick=function(){
    this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML="hello";
}
```

Both method/property are part of native DOM but I wonder if the latter is slightly faster than the former since getElementById should traverse all the ID of the document until the first match is reached?

Comment: You can profile the code yourself: http://jsperf.com/, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: @Frank Dai, please consider not only the faster but also the maintenance of that code. Let's say in the future, you want to put a simple image in between. Then, things like "this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML" will stop working.

Comment: Yes. I know to cache and this kind of relation-based code is vulnerable to future modification. My point is being that which way is faster even the difference might less than 2-3 ms.

Comment: Which way is "faster" is irrelevant. There is **no** performance problem with the code; see my comment on Joe's answer. Just Don't Worry about it; go find the 3% of the code that would actually benefit from being optimized..

Answer (score 0):

Even faster, is to cache the elements when the page loads, for future lookups:

```
var fooEl = document.getElementById("foo");
var barEl = document.getElementById("bar");

fooEl.onclick=function(){
    barEl.innerHTML="hello";
}
```

You should cache any lookup or calculation that 1) is expensive and 2) will never change. And you should do the lookup when the page loads, so that the lookups don't occur *after* the user has done some action, but the lookup occurs while the user is doing nothing (during this time, the user is doing nothing, it's free for you to do pre-loading and pre-caching of things).

Comment: Performing the lookup in a click handler won't be a bottleneck by any means. (I max at about 8 clicks/seconds when clicking like a cola'd up coder.) Fetching the element by ID is also a very fast operation (and the two-look linear follow is hardly an expensive operation either), considering. Since "caching" the elements may be problematic if the DOM is modified later (although the specific click binding makes this not likely), I wouldn't do so unless being bound a closure (variable) added a benefit. There is *no* performance issue with code and thus the only concern is clarity/maintainability.